# Twitter4j - Bad Authentication data. code - 215

Tags: twitter4j

I am newbie with Twitter4J API. I am looking to validate my access, but I can't.

```
public class Buscador { 
public static void main(String [] args) throws TwitterException{

    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
     cb.setDebugEnabled (true)
       .setOAuthConsumerKey ("********************")
       .setOAuthConsumerSecret ("********************")
       .setOAuthAccessToken ("********************")
       .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret ("********************");

    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory (cb.build ());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance (); 

    Query query = new Query("avantis_bc");
    QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);

    do{

              List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();

              for(Status tweet: tweets){
                   System.out.println("Usuário: "+tweet.getUser().getScreenName() + " Tweet: "+tweet.getText());
              }

              query = result.nextQuery();

              if(query!=null)
                   result = twitter.search(query);
    }while(query!=null);
}
```

}

Exception in thread "main" 400:The request was invalid. An accompanying error message

will explain why. This is the status code will be returned during version 1.0 rate

limiting(https://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate-limiting). In API v1.1, a request without

authentication is considered invalid and you will get this response.

message - Bad Authentication data.

code - 215

Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:

```
http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=506c3b98 or

http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=10b457b8
```

TwitterException{exceptionCode=[506c3b98-10b457b8], statusCode=400, message=Bad

Authentication data., code=215, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.3}

```
at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:163)

at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:53)

at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.get(HttpClientBase.java:71)

at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.get(TwitterImpl.java:1562)

at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.search(TwitterImpl.java:253)

at Buscador.main(Buscador.java:54)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just check the code and it works, the output is
`Usuário: bullshitbuffetx Tweet: one time me n quade went to avantis and i wore my braid hoodie n he had on a braid shirt, he zipped up his jacket bc he was so embarassed`

You should review your OAuth, maybe you put it wrong.

 Remember that you need to make your application on Twitter and then use your credentials.

Comment: Thank you for your help FeanDoe. Really my OAuth was wrong, had a space at the end of key.